# d3: UI lags when mouse events attached to 1000 nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a use-case where I have got about 1000 DOM element, and all of them are attached to mouseover and mouseout events.

This is how the code looks like

```
    onMouseover(node, targetNode) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.mouseoutAnimationFrame);
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.mouseoverAnimationFrame);
        this.mouseoverAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            svg.selectAll('use').classed('fadeOut', true);
            svg.selectAll('line').classed('fadeOut', true);
            svg.selectAll('text').classed('fadeOut', true);
            d3.select(targetNode).classed('fadeOut', false);
            d3.select(targetNode.nextElementSibling).classed('fadeOut', false);
            ...some more code
        return this;
    }


    onMouseout(node, target) {
        var svg = d3.select(target.ownerSVGElement);

        this.mouseoutAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            svg
                .selectAll('use')
                .classed('fadeOut', false)
                .classed('fadeIn', true);
            svg
                .selectAll('text')
                .classed('fadeOut', false)
                .classed('fadeIn', true);
        });
        return this;
    }

    registerListernerWithDelay(ele, delay, mouseoverCb, mouseoutCb) {
        var timeout = null;
        var event;

        ele.on('mouseover', function(d) {
            event = d3.event;
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                mouseoverCb(d, event);
            }, delay);
        });

        ele.on('mouseout', function(d) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            event = d3.event;
            mouseoutCb(d, event);
        });
    }
// I tried adding 400ms delay..still facing same issue
   this.registerListernerWithDelay(nodes, 400,
            function mouseover(d, event) {
                var target = event.target;
                self.onMouseover(d, target);
            },
            function mouseout(d,event) {
                var target = event.target;
                self.onMouseout(d, target);
            }
        );
```

So whenever I **hover** to elements..I see a **trail of information getting displayed**, which ideally should be removed on mouseout. Please suggest how do I overcome this bug. I tried adding delay also, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to solve this.

Instead of having one listener for each DOM node, you only use one listener on a parent node. 
Then whenever the event happens, you lookup `event.target` to identify which node should be animated.

Example implementation, assuming you have the following html:

```
<svg id="parentNode">
    <!-- All the interactive nodes are here... -->
</svg>
```

then this javascript does the trick:

```
d3.selectAll('#parentNode') // this is only one item
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        var element = d3.select(d3.event.target)
        // element is the DOM node with which you want to interact...
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        var element = d3.select(d3.event.target)
        // [...]
    })
```